# Polymer project, touch events

Tags: javascript, polymer

I may be dumb, but can't find any info about it.

If I want to attach a JavaScript function to the event for a mouse up I do it this way:

```
<div id="div1" on-mouseup={{menuMouseUp}}></div>
```

What are the key words for touch events? Is it on-touch-start, on-touchstart.. ?
Or it's not supported and we need to use pointers:
http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/pointer-events.html

I'm trying to test it on Ipad and no luck at all.
Cheers!

Comment: on-mouseup or on-touchstart should work fine. You might want to post a more complete code sample so we can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, Polymer implements a set of high-level events that unify a few different underlying event models.

For example, when using Polymer, instead of `click` you can use `tap`. Instead of `mouseup` you can use `up`. The Polymer equivalents work for mouse or touch.

There is some detailed information here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/ba4aDyOozm8/Hw0GJLvcOCMJ

Comment: it's still really fresh but it's getting there (I guess in a bit this will be the right answer ;) ).. also these events work fine on-touchstart, on-touchend, on-touchmove.. the only problems I get now are some random browsers' default behaviours, in some cases event.preventDefault() copes well, but sometimes it's still an issue

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Polymer team itself uses the polymer-gesture events 100% of the time, so if you have problems with those events, bug reports are in order. If you use the low-level events, you are asking for pain in the long run.

Comment: yeah, they're fine but as mentioned in the page you've attached, those more complex are not implemented yet - once it's done it'll be perfect

for now I just need something quick, so used the "on-touchmove" which didn't work for me in the first place because of missing "e.preventDefault" on the parent element - so the actual event was never raised because IPAD took it over..

Comment: The only things not implemented yet are things like pinch and zoom. Instead of 'touchmove', you should use the 'track' events, which are fully implemented.